# jQuery TextBox type over text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt

I am looking for code/plug-in/whatever that will make a textbox behave similar to what happens when you press the Insert button in a text editor and anything you type is typed over existing text. I am new to web dev, please be little specific. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A lightweight way to do this is the [labelOver plugin](http://remysharp.com/2007/03/19/a-few-more-jquery-plugins-crop-labelover-and-pluck/#labelOver), you can see a [demo here](http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/03/label_over_example.html).

Your markup looks something like this:

```
<div class="label"> 
  <label for="applied">Applied</label> 
  <input type="text" id="applied" /> 
</div>
```

Then the jQuery:

```
$('label').labelOver('over');
```

You adjust the CSS for your needs, look at the demo page for an example. For source, [look here](http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/03/label_over.js), very lightweight.  Another big plus that some alternative plugin's *don't* do: it also degrades gracefully with JavaScript disabled, and since clicking a label for an input focuses it in any browser, it's using the built-in behavior as a fall-back.

There are alternatives certainly, but after trying several, this is the one I settled on: for size, ability to customize styling easily, etc.

Comment: This is an interesting and useful plugin, but it doesn't seem to do what I need. This just shows a text over a text-field, while I need to change the characters of the text-field when user starts typing in. ie. text-field contains "12345" when user puts cursor at beginning and types '9' the textbox content becomes "92345", NOT "912345".

Comment: @m0s - Ahh, not sure there are plugins for this, you're basically looking for the `ins` key to be pressed on the keyboard, that kind of functionality?

Comment: Yes... I need this for a very specific textbox in my app.

Comment: @m0s - Sorry...I've never seen a plugin like this...the browser range code is all very ugly, this is the route you'll have to go down AFAIK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse  Just curious, say a person selects some text and starts type, selecting more than 1 letter, what would happen?

Comment: np. been googling for a solution for couple hours, found nothing. I thought this kind of things should be easy to do in web, but oh well...

good question :D in my case I would either not let them select at all, or would change only the first character in the selection leaving the rest unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this  [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) ? and here you have the [demo](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html) .